# SFSafariViewController background audio after closing

Tags: ios, sfsafariviewcontroller

I have an app that loads a webpage using `SFSafariViewController` and the user listen to some audios.

I want to keep the audio playing even if the user closes `SFSafariViewController`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible.
For use  **SFSafariViewController** controller as property not local variable.
ex.

```
var safariCtrl:SFSafariViewController!

func openSafariCtrl() {
     if safariCtrl == nil {
        safariCtrl = SFSafariViewController(url: YOUR_URL)
     }
     present(safariCtrl, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: It works but not perfeclty. I also need to keep playing when the app is in background. Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't answer the posted question about the audio while the app is in background.